# How do I get part of an iteration to repeat based on a certain condition?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to make labels to put onto products customers have purchased in the shopify store I admin. The code below does just about everything I need except for "repeating itself" when a customer has purchased more than one of the products in the iteration.

```
{% for line_item in line_items %}
      <br>
        </br>
        <br>
        </br>
     <div style="margin: 0 0 0em 0; padding: 0em; height: 60px; width: 140px;font-size: 12px;"><tr>
        <td><b>{{ line_item.title}}</b></td>
        <div>
        <td><b>{{ order_name }}</b></td>
      </tr>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question :-| however, have u try `for ... if this then do sth else do others endif endfor `

Comment: Is this what is required? Irrespective of the number of different products a customer has purchased in an order, you want to display only one label per order?

Answer (score 0):

```
Took some time and was able to figure it out myself!

{% for line_item in line_items %}
{% assign my_limit = line_item.quantity %}
{% for line_items in (1..my_limit) %}
     <br>`enter code here`
    </br>
    <br>
    </br>
    <div style="margin: 0 0 0em 0; padding: 0em; height: 60px; width: 140px;font-size: 12px;"><tr>
    <td><b>{{ line_item.title}} X{{line_item.quantity}}</b></td>
    <div>
    <td><b>{{ order_name }}</b></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just repeat the same data multiple times?